# Highlight.js applied to a knockoutjs template

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, highlight.js

I have a web page that uses `highlight.js` in this way:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://yandex.st/highlightjs/8.0/styles/vs.min.css">
<script src="http://yandex.st/highlightjs/8.0/highlight.min.js"></script>
<script>hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();</script>
```

Using Knockoutjs I need to bind some scripts template like this:

```
<section>
   <div data-bind="with: selectedTable">
       <div data-bind="template: { name: 'plugin-template' }"></div>
   </div>
</section>

<script type="text/html" id="plugin-template">
   <div id="plugin-view-content" data-bind="with: selectedPlugin, visible: selectedPlugin">
      <pre><code><p data-bind="text: code"></p></code></pre>
   </div>
</script>
```

My problem is that when the template is rendered, the text is not highlighted.
What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation on highlight.js states pretty clearly how you need to do if you want to highlight text which is dynamically added. It is stated under the heading `Custom Initialization` on http://highlightjs.org/usage/.

It states that you should call the `hljs.highlightBlock` function, passing in the element which contains the code you want highlighted.

In a KnockoutJS world, you should probably create a bindingHandler which changes the text of your field and then calls the highlight.js method which highlights the text properly. A simple version of such a bindingHandler could be something like the following:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.highlightedCode = {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor){
        var code = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
        element.innerText = code;
        hljs.highlightBlock(element);
    }
};
```

Given the following view model setup:

```
function ViewModel(code){
    var self = this;

    self.code = ko.observable(code);
}

var viewModel = new ViewModel('public static void Main()\n{\n    var name = Console.ReadLine();\n    Console.WriteLine("Hello " + name + "!");\n}');
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

You could use the bindingHandler with the following HTML:

```
<pre>
    <code data-bind="highlightedCode: code"></code>
</pre>
<textarea data-bind="value:code" rows="20" cols="100"></textarea>
```

I have created a jsfiddle containing this code, in case you want to try it out live. You can find the JSFiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/zY52s/